# 2013 Mazda 3 Engine not turning off while pushing the start/stop button

Tags: engine, electrical, ignition, mazda-3, start-stop

My 2013 Mazda 3 does not turn off the engine while pressing the start/stop button. If I continuously press the start/stop button for three or four times then engine stops and goes to the acc mode. This problem occurs when the car runs for sometime after starting, immediately pushing the button after starting turns the engine off although. Anyone else had the same issue? this seems a strange issue..please advise what might be going wrong..

Comment: the mechanic made me to change the switch but it did not do any good ..

Comment: Ive seen this a few times. If i remember correctly it was a problem with the steering lock module.

Comment: thank you @narkeleptk ..it might be the issue..so the whole steering lock module needs to be replaced?

Comment: Should be all if its the problem. I only do diag/keys/programming but the last one I was diagnosing for a local shop who called me to help with these same symptoms didn't believe me when I diagnosed it to the steering lock. Kept trying to tell me it was the keys even tho I walked them through all the programming. Never believing me and then finally giving up on the car, they sent it to the dealer. Later I was talking to the shop manager and he told me like it was some big shock that they replaced the steering lock and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a worn switch unit that detects the car is in "Park".  Mazda issued a Service Bulletin regarding this matter, with [instructions how to fix it](https://mazda.oemdtc.com/665/ignition-does-not-turn-off-when-pressing-startstop-button-2013-2014-mazda).

Comment: it's just not ignition but the engine does not turn off too...also, this happens when the car is driven for some time, immediately pushing the start/stop button after starting turns everything off..I don't think it's the parking switch problem, it might be the steering lock as mentioned by @narkeleptk..anyways thanks for your inputs :)